# Как сделать вертикальную палочку внутри инпута, не доходящую до границ?

Tags: html, css, css3

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать вертикальную палочку внутри инпута, не доходящую до границ и чтобы справа от нее был текст?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```css
input {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
}

p {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 5px 0;
}

span {
  border-left: 1px solid;
  padding: 0 6px;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <input type="text">
  <span>text</span>
</p>
```

Comment: У вас получилось!

Answer (score 4):

А вертикальная палочка, это `border-left`

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
}

input {
  width: 200px;
  padding-right: 25px;
  padding: 3px;
}

span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 3.5px;
  right: 0;
  border-left: 1px solid red;
  padding-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="text" />
  <span>text</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86785/discussion-on-answer-by-air--------).